# Self joins in rails 5.0 using postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create self join in rails.

```
class ItemGroup < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, class_name: "ItemGroup", foreign_key: "parent_id"

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: "ItemGroup"
end
```

This is my code but when ever i try to add new record it doesn't saves it. So what is the problem in this code can any one help me or give me idea about self join.

```
class CreateItemGroups < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :item_groups do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :parent_id
      t.text :description
      t.references :parent, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And this is my migration file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rails 5 makes `belongs_to` association required by default. To disable it you need to add `optional: true` to `belongs_to`

```
belongs_to :parent, class_name: "ItemGroup", optional: true
```

Comment: thank you ... it worked... so can you tell me how to access data also

Comment: <td> <%= f.parent.name %> </td> i tried to use this but it didn't provide me name

Comment: here f is an looping parameter

Comment: Not, sure but maybe `name` is blank. `parent` record is exists for `f`. try to change to `<%= f.parent.id %>`